# Accessing AWS Lambda using Google's Apigee

Tags: authentication, aws-lambda, apigee

I want to access my Lambda function using Apigee.
1 - Function URL cannot be Public.
2 - IAM , No Auth also cannot be used.
Any extensions in Apigee which requires access Key or secret ID also we can't use because IAM is out of option.

Comment: Have you considered IP check or certificate check?

Comment: I'm been working in the same solution and I could it connected by passing the Lambda function through API gateway aws, then from apigee I create a API reverse proxy pointing to api gateway URL generated, and at the end apigee from my approach is working like a forwarding gate. I shared it to give you one idea, did you get any other solution ? it would be useful if you can share it; in fact I'm thinking to open a question about this, cos I'm not totally sure if my approach it's correct